# Can anyone explain this javascript exploit?

Tags: javascript, reverse-engineering, malware, exploit, malware-detection

```js
var a = ['document', 'window', String];
var b = '108 111 99 97 116 105 111 110';
var c = '%68%74%74%70%73%3a%2f%2f%77%77%77%2e%74%75%6d%62%6c%72%2e%63%6f%6d';
var d = 'ZnJvbUNoYXJDb2Rl';
var e = 'ZGVjb2RlVVJJQ29tcG9uZW50';
var f = '1c2o3n4s5o6l7e8', g = '6a5l4e3r2t1';
function x(s) {
    var ss = s.split(' '); s = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) s += a[2][atob(d)](ss[i]);
    return s;
}
console = null;
function y(s) {
    var ss = '';
    for (var i = 1; i < s.length; i+= 2) ss += s[i];
    return ss;
}
a[1][y(f)] = a[1][y(g)] = null;
var s = a[0] + '["' + x(b) + '"]=' + a[1] + '["' + atob(e) + '"]("' + c + '")';
eval(s);
```

I am new to exploits and  would like to know what does this exploit do ?
How to do analysis for such exploits, what's the best approach to understand such things ?
I know basics of reverse engineering and assembly, but I was not able to figure out this one.

Comment: I've edited your question to remove the "Run this exploit in your browser" button, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a good place to ask people to explain long chunks of code — especially when that code is obfuscated — you might try a most specific question about some small part of the code you don't understand.

Comment: Just replace `eval` with `document.write` you will see decoded code.

Comment: This is barely even mangled. Just go through and replace a few values and you'll have the whole script.

Comment: It's not an exploit at all, it's just a really stupid script that redirects to Tumblr, might as well be `window.location = "https://www.tumblr.com"`, which is what it ends up as.

Comment: I edited my answer below to make it more detailled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It executes the following:

`document["location"]=windows["decodeURIComponent"]("https://www.tumblr.com")`

Which redirects you to tumblr.com.

It is pure obfuscation of code.

```
var s = a[0] + '["' + x(b) + '"]=' + a[1] + '["' + atob(e) + '"]("' + c + '")';
    ^   ^             ^              ^             ^                  ^
Payload=document["   (1)      "]= windows    [base64 encoded   ]( url http encoded string)
```

The following converts ascii character codes to string

```
(1): for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) s += a[2][atob(d)](ss[i])
```

The main aim of doing this is to hide from softwares looking for XSS like some antivirus. Yet this is only a payload, the real exploit would be a flaw allowing you to insert this on a legit web site to redirect to another website that may be a clone with just slightly different URL to trick someone. But it is more accurate to question about this on [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Node is a good tool to evaluate unsafe browser Javascript if you replace some things (like `atob`) by home made equivalents.